# Create an object from a python function returns a class

Tags: python

I have a function which returns a class:

```
def my_function():
    # some logic
    class AClass:
         def __init__(self, argument):
             init()
    return AClass
```

And when I call this function, it returns a class, not an object of that class, right?

```
Value = my_function()
```

My question is how can I create an object from that class `AClass`?

Thank you.

Comment: `instance = my_function()(argument)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
my_class = my_function()
my_obj = my_class(arg)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the method returns a reference to a type you can simply use whatever constructor that is defined for the class directly on the return value.

Take this class for example:

```py
class A:
    def __init_(self, n = 0):
        self.__n = n
```

Lets see what happens when reference the type directly when running the interpreter interactively:

```
>>> A
<class `__main__.A`>
```

Now lets return the type in a method:

```
>>> def f():
>>>    return A
>>> f()
<class `__main__.A`>
```

Since the value of referencing the class directly and when returned from a method is the same, you can use that returned value the same you would normally. Therefore `a = A()` is the same as `a = f()()`. Even if the class takes parameter you can still reference it directly: `a = f()(n = 10)`